# Why is this mdbootstrap carousel code resizing my images?

Tags: image, bootstrap-4, carousel, image-resizing, mdbootstrap

I'm using the carousel component provided here: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/javascript/carousel/
I want my pictures to be centered and in original size but instead, they're being stretched to fit the whole screen:
[image: https://imgur.com/a/zI8BkSs]

This is the code (I used the same random image for demonstration):

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Material Design Bootstrap</title>
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Start your project here-->
 <!--Card-->
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/14/13/04/nature-3474826_960_720.jpg"
        alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/14/13/04/nature-3474826_960_720.jpg"
        alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/14/13/04/nature-3474826_960_720.jpg"
        alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<!--/.Card-->
  <!-- Start your project here-->

  <!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual images which are used in the code are too big... and they've used the `w-100` class on `<img>` which is why

- you see the images shrunk (in case of mdBootstrap's default images)
- you see the images stretched (in case of your images)

I removed the file to show how a smaller image without being stretched will look... check the **snippet** below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block " src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/14/13/04/nature-3474826_960_720.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block " src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/JumboMob.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block " src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(33).jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block " src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(31).jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```